# Rails making three db calls to save one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

I have a very long method that creates an array of teams.  Each team associates with several users.  After the method is done and the teams are finalized, I'm trying to save all this info with as few db calls as possible.

Associations:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :objective
    belongs_to :consultancy
    has_one :seminar, :through => :consultancy
    belongs_to  :consultant, class_name: "Student"
    has_and_belongs_to_many  :users
end 

class User < Application 
    attr_accessor       :remember_token, :activation_token, :reset_token
    before_save         :downcase_stuff
    before_validation   :check_title, :check_user_number, :check_username, :check_password
    before_create       :create_activation_digest
    after_create        :update_last_login

    has_and_belongs_to_many  :teams
end
```

This is how I'm trying to save them:

```
    these_teams = []
    @teams.each_with_index do |team, index|
        these_teams[index] = Team.new(:consultancy_id => @consultancy.id, :consultant_id => team[:consultant_id], :objective_id => team[:objective_id], :bracket => team[:bracket])
        these_teams[index].user_ids = team[:user_ids]
    end

    Team.transaction do
        these_teams.each do |this_team|
            this_team.save!
        end
    end
```

Here is a sample of the sql reading when I run this code in a local server.  This is just for one of the teams.  All of this is repeated for all twelve teams that I'm trying to save.

```
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = ? LIMIT ?  [["username", "jo16"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER(?) AND ("users"."id" != ?) LIMIT ?  [["email", "example-22@railstutorial.org"], ["id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Student Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Student') AND "users"."username" = ? AND ("users"."id" != ?) LIMIT ?  [["username", "jo16"], ["id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = ? LIMIT ?  [["username", "kg19"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER(?) AND ("users"."id" != ?) LIMIT ?  [["email", "example-25@railstutorial.org"], ["id", 19], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Student Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Student') AND "users"."username" = ? AND ("users"."id" != ?) LIMIT ?  [["username", "kg19"], ["id", 19], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = ? LIMIT ?  [["username", "es32"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER(?) AND ("users"."id" != ?) LIMIT ?  [["email", "example-38@railstutorial.org"], ["id", 32], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Student Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Student') AND "users"."username" = ? AND ("users"."id" != ?) LIMIT ?  [["username", "es32"], ["id", 32], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "teams" ("consultancy_id", "objective_id", "consultant_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["consultancy_id", 66], ["objective_id", 2], ["consultant_id", 16], ["created_at", 2019-11-07 03:57:17 UTC], ["updated_at", 2019-11-07 03:57:17 UTC]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "teams_users" ("user_id", "team_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 16], ["team_id", 311], ["created_at", 2019-11-07 03:57:17 UTC], ["updated_at", 2019-11-07 03:57:17 UTC]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "teams_users" ("user_id", "team_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 19], ["team_id", 311], ["created_at", 2019-11-07 03:57:17 UTC], ["updated_at", 2019-11-07 03:57:17 UTC]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "teams_users" ("user_id", "team_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["user_id", 32], ["team_id", 311], ["created_at", 2019-11-07 03:57:17 UTC], ["updated_at", 2019-11-07 03:57:17 UTC]]
```

So it appears that there are three separate calls for each member of the team. One for "User Load", one for "User Exists", and one for "Student Exists".  I've also tried to eager load the users before calling this method, but I might not be doing that correctly.

Is it possible for me to decrease the calls being made here?  What other info would be useful for me to include in this question?

Thank you in advance for any insight.

Comment: So, as per your question, you need to save team and team_users?? Also, please share the associations

Comment: Most probably these calls originate from validations. Please post which validations and callbacks you gave in mentioned models.

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari Yes.  Team has_and_belongs_to_many users.  I've also set up a team_users table.  Can I improve performance if I delete this table?  I updated the question to include the Team model and its associations.

Comment: @Vasfed, I don't think there are any validations or callbacks involved with this process, at least not in the model file.

Comment: When you add a foreign key using rails CLI, It adds an index over that foreign key too be default. So while saving an associated record (team users - in this case), it automatically validates the presence of associated records (user - in this case)

Comment: @M.Habib, Ok.  Thank you.  So then the only way I can think of to reduce db calls would be to save the user_ids as simple integers, rather than references.  Does this sound accurate?

Comment: @JeffZivkovic you can do that, but I will not recommend doing this. This call is worth its purpose.